# How would i iterate over a 2d array of varying size in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm currently creating a brickbreaker (or breakout, like atari breakout) and for the bricks im using a 2d array:

```
private Brick bricks[][] = new Brick[10][41];
```

To destroy a specific Brick (for whatever reason i have to destroy that), i created a method:

```
public void destroyBrick(Brick brick) {
    for(int x = 0; x < bricks[x].length; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < bricks[y].length; y++) {
            if (bricks[x][y].equals(brick)) {
                bricks[x][y] = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The way the array is created is the following:

```
for(int j=0; j<bricks[0].length; j++){ 
  for(int i=0; i<bricks.length; i++){ 
    bricks[i][j]=new Brick(game,10,Color.GREEN,j*margin,i*margin); 
  }
}
```

Now for some reason the counter for x eventually reaches 10 and the counter for y reaches 0 where it crashes, and i can't figure out why.

Is there a different way of iterating a 2d array that has different values for columns and rows?

**note**
The reason the formatting and my spelling is so rubbish is, that im writing this on the app version. Feel free to correct any mistakes or formatting errors, before i can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are referencing `y` in the loop that iterates on it. This compiles correctly, because `y` is defined at the point of reference, but it does not do what you need. In addition, the outer loop should stop upon reaching `bricks.length`, not `bricks[x].length`.

These two lines

```
for(int x = 0; x < bricks[x].length; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < bricks[y].length; y++) {
```

should be

```
for(int x = 0; x < bricks.length; x++) {
//                       ^
    for(int y = 0; y < bricks[x].length; y++) {
    //                        ^
```

Comment: This throws the same error, just later in the iteration (so x is 9 and y is 40 )

Comment: @Reteras `(9,40)` is a valid pair of indexes, are you sure that your array has been properly initialized (i.e. `bricks[9]` has a non-`null` array in it)?

Comment: it worked thanks! Now off dealing with nullpointers this results in :|

Answer (score 3):

The first int x doesn't refer to what you need, I think.
x ranges from 0 to the length of the array indexed with x, that is 41.

```
for (int x = 0; x < bricks.length; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < bricks[x].length; y++)
```

Should work (at least I wrote this without testing)

Answer (score 1):

Try iterating with any of this

```
public void destroyBrick(Brick brick) {
    for(int x = 0; x < bricks.length; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < bricks[0].length; y++) {
            if (bricks[x][y].equals(brick)) {
                bricks[x][y] = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
public void destroyBrick(Brick brick) {
    for(int x = 0; x < bricks.length; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < bricks[x].length; y++) {
            if (bricks[x][y].equals(brick)) {
                bricks[x][y] = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if there's any other error, use your debugger to find out where exactly